# How to add sound Effects on a sound file in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5, android-ndk-r7

How to give audio effect for a mp3 file in android.For example echo effect  mix some back ground music ect.

Comment: Hi Rojesh nice question... You can use audio manager a in android.                                                             I found one sample on this link http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-audio-demo-audiotrack.html